# How to unlock a folder in the Save File dialog previously locked in PgAdmin 4?

Tags: linux, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I accidentally locked the folder Desktop from the Save File dialog

[image: 1]

When i try to select this folder pops up the message

[image: 2]

Can u help me to unlock?

Comment: How did you locked it?

Comment: At the first selection of folder in which save file, it is asked if the folder is secure, and I mistakenly choose "No" and so it's locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having just done a similar thing, you can get access to the folder in your Privacy Accessibility settings.  I am on a MacOS and it allowed me to check the box and the lock symbol disappeared.